# Caching the results of a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, caching

For a project, I would like to cache the results computed by a method.
Some constraints:

- I can't use Python3
- I can't use 3rd party modules

What I've come up so far is this:

```
def cached_method(fun):
    """A memoize decorator for class methods."""
    @functools.wraps(fun)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Return the value if cached.
        Get it, cache it and return it if not.
        """
        try:
            self._cache[fun]
        except AttributeError:
            self._cache = {}
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return self._cache.setdefault(fun, {}).setdefault((args, tuple(kwargs.items())), fun(self, *args, **kwargs))

    return get
```

However, there's something wrong. In fact, using a minimal example, such as this:

```
class TestClass(object):

    @cached_method
    def method(self, p_arg):
        print 'sentinel'
        return p_arg

sut = TestClass()
sut.method(2)
sut.method(2)
```

You'll see the method is called twice ('sentinel' is printed twice)

Inspecting it via PDB I can't see what the problem is, given the second time `_cache` is effectively containing all what's needed.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, the issue is with `setdefault` which calls the argument passed as default (the second) regardless whether the key is found or not.

To fix that problem, replace the `return` line above with:

```
results = self.cache.setdefault(fun, {})

try:
    ret = results[(args, tuple(kwargs.items()))]
except KeyError:
    ret = results[(args, tuple(kwargs.items()))] = fun(self, *args, **kwargs)

return ret
```

Comment: `fun(self, *args, **kwargs)` _calls_ the function, even if that's the 2nd argument to `setdefault`. You have to check if the result exists in the cache, and only call the function if the cache lookup comes up empty.

Comment: I think you mean: `try: return self._cache[fun]`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey that's the issue - for some reason I thought `setdefault` didn't use the second argument (the default) if the key was there. Fixing that fixes the problem.

Comment: @quamrana, not really, that was intentional - if you return at that point you return a dictionary of results, which is not what was intended. You could argue you can use those intermediate results later on, but that, IMO, was complicating the whole function.

Comment: I've accepted to close the question as duplicate, but as mentioned above, I'll stick with the code used here, rather than using the fully-fledged `lru_cache` implementation, being more simple for my purpose.

Comment: Maybe I meant: `try: return self._cache[fun][(args,kwargs)]`

Comment: @quamrana Unfortunately in that case, if you trigger `KeyError` you don't know where it comes from. To find out you could inspect the exception, then again you'd complicate the code more.

Comment: It works for me.